# Spring elasticsearch - limit result based on percentage range of score?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

We are currently returning many documents for each index we are searching in. But score for each document could be very different. eg score of 1st object = 5, score of 50th object = 0.0001. In this case we can definitely say thay we don't need objects with so low score.

We want to limit the search result via 80% score of the first result. For example, if the first result score is 5, then we will just show records where score is between 4-5 (since 80% of 5 is 4)

Is this possible in spring elasticsearch?

Comment: I dont think so its possible. but you can limit result using `size` param.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Elastic query to return only max score records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56058104/elastic-query-to-return-only-max-score-records) and [ElasticSearch max score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34860389/elasticsearch-max-score). Even with adding a filter query it seems not possible (at least not without some complex scripting) to achieve this.

What I'd do: Use paged request with a page size of let's say 10. When reading the first result, the `SearchHits<T>` returned by Spring Data Elasticsearch contains the `maxScore` of the result. With this value you can calculate your threshold value. Then keep reading the next page until you encounter the first element that has a score below that threshold value.